# Lock select options based on time and day

Tags: javascript, php

Building a website for a football pool for fun with membership features already done and having an issue with the main page, frankly I'm at a loss for how to do this page.

The page is a pick screen and this is my thinking, you pick a team from a drop down select option list and it is sent to a database(mySQL) so the Admin can keep track. The catch is I need certain restrictions on when you can pick; Pick screen gets disabled certain times and days based on when a team plays, if a team plays on Thursday at 8pm then I need only that team disabled from select list 1 hour before game time until next week.

Not sure if I'm going in right direction or if I'm horribly off, so clarity would be appreciated, open to using Javascript or PHP, whatever is easiest to get full functionality for my purposes.

```
<form action="login_success.php" method="POST">
<fieldset>
   <legend>Pick</legend>
    <select id="tm1" name="teams">
    <option value="wr">Washington Redskins</option>
    <option value="nyg">New York Giants</option>
    <option value="pe">Philadelphia Eagles</option>
    <option value="dc">Dallas Cowboys</option>
    <option value="br">Baltimore Ravens</option>
    <option value="ps">Pittsburgh Steelers</option>
    <option value="tt">Tennessee Titans</option>
    <option value="gbp">Green Bay Packers</option>
    <option value="ss">Seattle Seahawks</option>
    <option value="cbr">Cleveland Browns</option>
    <option value="bb">Buffalo Bills</option>
    <option value="jj">Jacksonville Jaguars</option>
    <option value="ic">Indianapolis Colts</option>
    <option value="ht">Houston Texans</option>
    <option value="kcc">Kansas City Chiefs</option>
    <option value="md">Miami Dolphins</option>
    <option value="nep">New England Patriots</option>
    <option value="nyj">New York Jets</option>
    <option value="slr">Saint Louis Rams</option>
    <option value="nos">New Orleans Saints</option>
    <option value="mv">Minnesota Vikings</option>
    <option value="tbb">Tampa Bay Buccaneers</option>
    <option value="ac">Arizona Cardinals</option>
    <option value="af">Atlanta Falcons</option>
    <option value="sf49">San Francisco 49ers</option>
    <option value="sdc">San Diego Chargers</option>
    <option value="or">Oakland Raiders</option>
    <option value="db">Denver Broncos</option>
    <option value="cbe">Cincinnati Bengals</option>
    <option value="cp">Carolina Panthers</option>
    <option value="dl">Detroit Lions</option>
    <option value="cbea">Chicago Bears</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </fieldset>
 </form>

 <?php
//If statement to control pick selection "disabled/enabled"
if(strtotime("Today") == strtotime("Thursday") || strtotime("Friday") ||   strtotime("Saturday") || strtotime("Sunday") || strtotime("Monday")) {
    echo '<h2 style = "text-align: center">Make a selection! Pick(s) are now  available</h2>';
    $pick = $_POST['teams'];
    $picked = isset($_POST['teams']);
if($picked) {
    echo '<br><p style = "text-align: center">You have made a selection, feel free to change your pick until ONE HOUR before game time.<p><br>';
}
}
    ?>
```

Comment: Do everything based on server time and UTC. Disable options based on server time on page load with a delay until the next update (say in seconds or milliseconds). At the end of the delay, do an XMLHttpRequest from time to time to update the disabled options and set the delay for the next update (might be in a few minutes, hours or even days).

Comment: paragraphing to improve readability